# Maria DB Regular Expression

Tags: regex, mariadb

I wrote a query for finding data from a table in which the word I find occur.

```
SELECT tr.track_order AS `order`, tr.title AS title  
FROM tracks tr
LEFT JOIN `options` op ON tr.id = op.track_id
WHERE tr.sim_id ='sdf' AND
(tr.description REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]])'
```

It works well. But when the word I will find contain special characters at the beginning or at the end then this query is not working as I want.
Actually, I want to replace those words with new words.
Can any suggest the write regular expression?
Could you help me?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this with a regex and not simply use [`REPLACE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp)?

Comment: Because I want to give this find-and-replace functionality to the end user.

Comment: If this instance supports PCRE, this should be something like `(?!\B\w)` + escaped `word` + `(?<!\w\B)`

Comment: can you give me real example.

Comment: It will give those words also which are part of some string for example "asds" I search ds. it give me row but i only want to find whole word not part of some string

Comment: You have unmatched parentheses in the regexp. Did you mean `(word)` instead of `)word(`?

Comment: The basic problem is that word boundary patterns like `[[:<:]]` only match where there's a word character (alphanumeric) next to a non-word character (special characters). You can't use it if the word begins or ends with a special character, because then there's no boundary at that place.

Comment: unmatched parentheses is copy paste issue otherwise it is correctly